# Bash: Killing all processes in subprocess

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, kill

In bash I can get the process ID (`pid`) of the last subprocess through the `$!` variable. I can then kill this subprocess before it finishes:

```
(sleep 5) & pid=$!
kill -9 $pid
```

This works as advertised. If I now extend the subprocess with more commands after the `sleep`, the `sleep` command continues after the subprocess is killed, even though the other commands never get executed.

As an example, consider the following, which spins up a subprocess and monitor its assassination using `ps`:

```
# Start subprocess and get its pid
(sleep 5; echo done) & pid=$!

# grep for subprocess
echo "grep before kill:"
ps aux | grep "$pid\|sleep 5"

# Kill the subprocess
echo
echo "Killing process $pid"
kill -9 $pid

# grep for subprocess
echo
echo "grep after kill:"
ps aux | grep "$pid\|sleep 5"

# Wait for sleep to finish
sleep 6

# grep for subprocess
echo
echo "grep after sleep is finished:"
ps aux | grep "$pid\|sleep 5"
```

If I save this to a file named `filename` and run it, I get this printout:

```
grep before kill:
username    7464    <...>    bash filename
username    7466    <...>    sleep 5
username    7467    <...>    grep 7464\|sleep 5

Killing process 7464

grep after kill:
username    7466    <...>    sleep 5
username    7469    <...>    grep 7464\|sleep 5

grep after sleep is finished:
username    7472    <...>    grep 7464\|sleep 5
```

where unimportant information from the `ps` command is replaced with `<...>`. It looks like the `kill` has killed the overall bash execution of `filename`, while leaving `sleep` running.

How can I correctly kill the entire subprocess?

Comment: hint: is it still there?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Is what still there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a trap in the subshell to kill any active jobs before exiting:

```
 (trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT; sleep 5; echo done ) & pid=$!
```

Comment: This does not work for me. What is `jobs -p` supposed to output? It doesn't output anything when I run it.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention one important point: you need to not use `kill -9`, because that causes the OS to kill the process *immediately*, without giving it a chance to run its `EXIT` handler. `kill` by itself is sufficient.

Comment: `jobs -p` lists the process IDs of all currently active jobs managed by the shell.

Comment: Yup, without the `-9` option to kill, this does work. This also explains why `jobs -p` didn't output anything before (the command was never run).

Comment: You should never need to use `kill -9` for normal work; it is intended to kill buggy programs that aren't responding to normal means to kill them.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly why that sleep process gets orphaned, anyway instead kill you can use pkill with -P flag to <del>also</del> kill all children

```
pkill -TERM -P $pid
```

EDIT:
that means that in order to kill a process and all it's children you should use instead

```
CPIDS=`pgrep -P $pid` # gets pids of child processes
kill -9 $pid
for cpid in $CPIDS ; do kill -9 $cpid ; done
```

Comment: Shells don't usually send signals they receive to their children.  But this isn't obvious because at the terminal, if you run sleep, the child gets the signal directly.

Comment: This does kill `sleep`, but interestingly `echo done` gets executed. I can fix this by chaining the commands in the subprocess together with `&&` instead of `;`, leading to a working solution.

Comment: @jmd_dk - I was actually wrong, when I said, that it kills **also** kills all children, actually it kills only all children, I will edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at `rkill` that seems to meet your requirements :

http://www.unix.com/man-page/debian/1/rkill/

> rkill [-SIG] pid/name...
>
> When invoked as rkill, this utility does not display information about the processes, but
>        sends them all a signal instead.  If not specified on the command line, a terminate
>        (SIGTERM) signal is sent.

Comment: Works, though `rkill`/`pslist` does not seem to be standard tool installed on most Linux systems.